# How to force to stop Gradle Build Running in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I run an app with Android Studio, the build takes a lot of time to execute, after few minutes, I decide to stop precess, but nothing happened.
Is there a way to kill Gradle process?
Thank You.

Comment: Close your project and Quit Android Studio. Restart your PC. This is the only method working for me.

Comment: @zackygaurav i thought next thing you will tell to "buy new system"

Comment: @zackygaurav that's to do when you're in panic

Answer (score 8):

you can call `./gradlew --stop` in a Terminal and it will kill all grade processes

It requires admin permission run this for permission before first command

```
$ chmod +x gradlew
```

OR

click left most button in image below which came in Android Studio 2.2

[image: Android studio tool bar screen shot]

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this solution, when I do that, in the next run, it make error caused by /cache.properties.lock. When I remove this file, it work.

Comment: what is the name of this icon? can't find it in the toolbar settings